# Segmentation fault in C program on first scanf line

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, structure

i am getting segmentation fault on the line where scanf is taking time as input ( i detected it using gdb and other tools ) what can be the possible reason for this? also when i ommit whole while loop then segmentation fault goes away. i am sorry if i am breaking the forum rules i am new here

```
   #include<stdio.h>
   #include<stdlib.h>
   #define DOWN 2
   #define UP 1

int time;
 struct cave
{ 
    long up;
    long down;
};

 int main()
{ //write(1,"h",1);

scanf("%d",&time);

while(time--)
{ 

    int flag=0;
    long n,h,i;
    long count=0;
    scanf("%ld %ld",&n,&h);
    struct cave o[1000000];
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%ld",&(o[i].down));
        scanf("%ld",&(o[i].up));
    }
    long countup[1000000]={0};
    long countdown[1000000]={0};
    long upi,downi;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        upi=o[i].up;
        downi=o[i].down;
        countup[upi]++;
        countdown[downi]++;
    }
    long maxup=0;
    long maxupindex=0;
    long maxdownindex=0;
    long maxdown=0;

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        upi=countup[i];
        downi=countdown[i];
        if(upi>maxup)
        {
            maxup=upi;
            maxupindex=i;
        }
        if(downi>maxdown)
        {
            maxdown=downi;
            maxdownindex=i;
        }

    }
    long index;
    if(maxdown>maxup)
    {index=maxdownindex;flag=DOWN;
    }

    else
    {index=maxupindex; flag=UP;}
    long indexup=index+h-1;
    long indexdown=index-h+1;

        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{       
        upi=o[i].up;
        downi=o[i].down;
        if(flag==DOWN)
    {

            if(upi<indexup)
            {
            count=count+indexup-downi;
            }
            if(downi>index)
            {
            count=count+downi-index;
            }

    }
    if(flag==UP)
    {


            if(upi<index)
            {
            count=count+index-upi;
            }
            if(downi>indexdown)
            {
            count=count+downi-indexdown;
            }

        }
    }
    printf("%ld\n",count);  





}
}
```

Comment: Your assumption does not look far enough. The first `scanf("%d",&time);` where `int time;` is correct. So when you omit the whole `while` loop the problem is within that.

Comment: when formatting code: 1) always indent after every opening brace '{'  and un-indent before every closing brace '}'   2) never use tabs for indenting as every wordprocessor/editor has the tab stops/tap widths set differently.  3) suggest using 4 spaces for indenting as that is wide enough to be clearly visible, even with variable width fonts and not so wide that it eats up the width of the editor/printable page with only a small number of indent levels.

Comment: when #define'ing numeric values, always wrap the numeric values with parens to avoid 'text replacement' errors

Comment: when calling the scanf() and family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: 1) please use meaningful names for variables.   2) 'time' is a well known function, it is a bad idea to use the well known function names for variable names  3) when requesting input from the user, always prompt the user as to what they are to input.  Otherwise the user is looking at a blinking cursor with no idea of what to do next.  4) the code is much more readable/understandable when code blocks (If, while, else, etc) are surrounded by a blank line before and after.

Comment: 5) a few key comments in the code makes your intent clear and we do not have to 'reverse engineer' the code to try and determine what you are trying to accomplish.  6) for readability/clarity in the code, only 1 variable per line, only one statement per line, (and generally) put open/close braces on separate lines and vertically aligned

Comment: there are  'struct cave' and 'long' being declared on the stack with length of 1million.   This is a 'good' way to overrun the available stack space.  suggest either 1) malloc those arrays, leaving just a pointer on the stack or 2) move them to the file global space.

Comment: the user input value could be 1000000 for the variable 'n'.   later in the code, the user is being ask to input 2xn long ints.   Really?  upto 2 million multicharacter entries for the user to input!   You might want to seriously re-think the algorithm

Comment: Please re-format the code for consistency, add appropriate comments, use meaningful variable names then repost the code.

Comment: You may be running out of stack space... an array of 1,000,000 `struct cave`'s will likely be nearly 8MB even with 4-byte `long`s

Answer (score -1):

I suspect the problem is that the scanf format string "%ld" tries to write to a 64-bit value.  But the "long" type is only guaranteed to be at least 32 bits (yes, the same size as an int is, in practice).  Try declaring your parameters to be of type long long -- they are required to be 64 bits long.

Comment: scanf `%ld` takes a pointer to a `long int`. It's an error to pass a `long long int *` to it. (And no, `long long` is not required to be 64 bits wide.)

Comment: True.  It's only guaranteed to be *at least* 64 bits wide according to the c99 standard.  http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf (see page 22).

As for %ld --> 64 bits, you're right there as well, I jumped the gun.  %lf *is* a 64-bit doulbe, but %ld is *only* a long int (aka 32 bits in most every implementation out there.)